# Best way to monitor end point usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm working on an API with a few legacy routes/controllers, and we're trying to calculate which are still in use and which are no longer needed.

Is there a gem that will do this out of the box? Or is this something I'd need to write a script for in the controllers?

Comment: You could just grep your server logs. No gems needed.

Comment: You can run `rake routes` in the console, or run the rails server and access `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` from a web browser to see all the end points.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev was hoping for something nice and pretty but maybe I'm being lazy

Comment: @Mark or you can set up a 3 LOC `before_action` in your base controller, which puts `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` to redis or something

Comment: [New Relic](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm) is a paid product but will provide this information.